# Avatar.js on SPARC

Tags: oracle, jvm, nashorn, sparc, avatarjs

Node JS application is working fine with Linux, windows and Solaris. But Node JS is not working in SPARC system because it is not supporting V8 engine.

Myself found a External project called AVATAR, which is used to run NODE JS Programs in JVM (Java Virtual Machine) using the JAVA 8 inbuilt JavaScript Engine – Nashron.

In their official site  they have provided me (.so) file for Linux, (.dll) file for Windows using that we compiled the program. By using those files (.so & .dll) we successfully executed Node JS programs in  Linux, windows with JAVA 8.

I used same linux (.so) file to run on SPARC platform and it throws below error.

**Error Occurred :**

```
-bash-4.1$ java -Djava.library.path=dist -jar dist/avatar-js.jar HttpServer.js

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /export/home/thiru/LinuxAVatar/dist/libavatar-js.so: ld.so.1: java: fatal: /export/home/thiru/LinuxAVatar/dist/libavatar-js.so: wrong ELF data format: ELFDATA2LSB (Possible cause: endianness mismatch)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)

        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)

        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)

        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)

        at com.oracle.libuv.LibUV.<clinit>(LibUV.java:33)

        at com.oracle.avatar.js.Server.<init>(Server.java:166)

        at com.oracle.avatar.js.Server.<init>(Server.java:140)

        at com.oracle.avatar.js.Server.<init>(Server.java:128)

        at com.oracle.avatar.js.Server.main(Server.java:122)
```

I have attached  the basic HTTP Server Program in NODE JS which I used to run in JVM using avatar.

Could you please provide some feasibility for the below points:

1.Running NODE JS on SPARC system,

2.Is there any build for that .so file for SPARC,

3.shall I use any other Java Script Engines instead of Nashron in SPARC (ex: Spider Monkey).

Link For Official Site: https://avatar-js.java.net/

Procedure to run Avatar : http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2014/03/running-nodejs-applications-on-jvm-with.html

Version of Oracle Solaris OS : Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC

JAVA Version : 
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Thanks in Advance.

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8585/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Project Avatar from Oracle is dead.
Officially it's called "development is on hold", but... you know!
See also my blogpost about this: http://www.n-k.de/2015/02/current-status-of-oracles-project-avatar.html
The mentioned alternative "Nodyn" is also dead.

So, you have to look for another option to run node.js on your desired platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dasniko. Is it wise using a alternative Javascript Engines instead of Nashorn ? Will it work with NODE JS and SPARC?

Comment: It depends what you want to achive.
If you just want to run Node.js code, you should look how to run Node.js on Sparc (I don't have any experience with Sparc platforms).
If you want to combine Java and JavaScript, Nashorn can be a possible solution, but then you might have to drop the node APIs.

Comment: I have found this GraalVM - New JIT Compiler and Polyglot Runtime for the JVM:   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oracle-labs/program-languages/overview/index.html . Its working NodeJS on SPARC System. :-)